# How to download multiple image from database in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In my **laravel 5.4** app, I want to download multiple images of the selected product from the database it is creating multiple zip file in `public_path('uploads/download-images');` but not downloading the file how can i download this.

what is the best possible way to download this?

what am i doing wrong ? can anybody help? thank in advance.

Following is my code.

```
public function downloads_all(Request $request) 
 {
    $public_dir = '';
    $$zipFileName = '';
    $zip = '';
    $product_images =  DB::table('product_images')
                ->where('deleted_at', null)
                ->whereIn('product_id',  explode(',', $request->ids))
                ->get();
    if ($product_images) 
    {
        foreach ($product_images as $value) 
        {
            $zipFileName = 'product_' . $value->product_id . '_images.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $public_dir = public_path('uploads/download-images');
            if (!is_dir($public_dir)) 
            {
                mkdir($public_dir, 0777, true);
            }
            if ($zip->open($public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) 
            {
                foreach ($product_images as $image) 
                {
                    $directory_path = base_path() . '/public/uploads/products/' . $image->product_id . '/images/';
                    $image_path = $image->image_path;
                    $file_name = basename($image_path);
                    $zip->addFile($directory_path . $file_name, $file_name);
                }
                $zip->close();
            }
        }

        $files = File::files(public_path('uploads/download-images'));
        $filecount = count($files);
        $filetopath = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < $filecount; $i++) 
        { 
            $filetopath = $public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName;
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'Expires' => 0,
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
                'Content-Length' => filesize($filetopath),
                'Cache-Control' => 'private, no-transform, no-store, must-revalidate',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $zipFileName . '"',
            );

            if (file_exists($filetopath)) 
            {
                return response()->download($filetopath, $zipFileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
            } 
            else 
            {
                return ['status'=>'zip file does not exist'];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return back();
    }
}
```

this is the js

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#download-master').on('click', function(e) 
    {
        if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
        {
            $(".multiple_download").prop('checked', true);  
        } else {  
            $(".multiple_download").prop('checked',false);  
        }  
    });

    $('.download-all').on('click', function(e) {

        var allVals = [];  
        $(".multiple_download:checked").each(function() {  
            allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });  

        if(allVals.length <=0)  
        {  
            alert("Please select row to download.");  
        }  
        else 
        {  
            var join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'POST',
                data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
                data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    alert('Seccussfully Downloaded');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            }); 
        }  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$directory_path` should be an absolute path, for example, `public_path('/uploads/products/')`, or `$zip->addFile` cannot read the file's content.

Comment: $directory_path is fine any other solution

Comment: It may works in laravel template blade files, because the web server will know what exactly `/` means, but in this situation the `/` is not web root. You can check the return value of `$res = $zip->addFile($directory_path.$file_name, $file_name);`, if you use a path starts with `/`, you will get `false`, if you use the absolute path, it works fine.

Comment: Just replace `$directory_path = '/public/uploads/products/';` with `$directory_path = 
 public_path('/uploads/products/');`

Comment: May be you need to check file if really exists before you add it to `ZipArchive`, just like the previous answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186411/discussion-between-shahid-hussain-and-rubys).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (file_exists($filetopath)) 
{
    return response()->download(storage_path($filetopath, $zipFileName, $headers));
}
```

Comment: @ShahidHussain Can you explain why it's not working? What kind of error does it give?